# Retrieve data from get route (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, get

I'm learning nodejs and database from a website.

In this website we have to reproduce the code below in order to retrieve the data from app.use('/server/profil');

Here is how I did it, but I have a problem :
The req.body from app.post retrieve an empty object. It should retrieve the studd object.

Need some help

Thank for those you can help me.

```
    const express = require('express');

    const app = express()
    const cors = require('cors');
    app.use(cors());

    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

    // so for every file we want on public we do not need to specify the path as it is allready         specified.
    // indeed this code give us this path http://localhost:3000/public
    app.use(express.static('public'));

    app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content, Accept,         Content-Type, Authorization');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS');
    next();
    });

    app.post('/server/profil', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.status(201).json({
    message: 'Thing created successfully!'
    });
    });

    app.use('/server/profil', (req, res, next) => {
    const stuff = [
    {
    _id: 'oeihfzeoi',
    title: 'My first thing',
    description: 'All of the info about my first thing',
    imageUrl: '',
    price: 4900,
    userId: 'qsomihvqios',
   },
   {
    _id: 'oeihfzeomoihi',
    title: 'My second thing',
    description: 'All of the info about my second thing',
    imageUrl: '',
    price: 2900,
    userId: 'qsomihvqios',
    },
    ];
    res.status(200).json(stuff);
    res.send(stuff);
    });

    module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the api by Postman and you need to use config your request.
Then you need to use something like query string or type of body request. (Check image below) [image]